# Is there any way to delete a question which has answers?

Tags: support, self-delete, answered-questions

I was wondering if there is any way of deleting a question which has answers? As if you do you cannot delete them, I understand that someone has taken the time to reply to my question and thus it's disrespectful to delete it, but I really need to delete my post. If a moderator could message me back it would be great. (If needed I can provide a reason for deletion though it is personal and would rather do it in a private chat if possible)

Comment: "I don't want my professor to search for the text of my homework problem and find my question" is too personal for meta?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to have a post deleted, flag it, and explain in your flag reason why you want it deleted. We may or may not act on the flag, depending on the reason.  If you want it deleted because it's homework, then most likely we will not delete it.

If [this is the question you're referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482567/a-few-problems-with-how-to-use-arraylists), I'm hesitant to unilaterally delete it. I can disassociate the post from your account, but I'm not going to delete it for the following reasons:

- **It sets a bad precedent**: Student uses Stack Overflow to get help on homework (or to have someone do their assignment for them).  They then want it deleted so they don't get into trouble.
- **Taking advantage of the community**: the Asker is taking advantage of the community to help them with something they know they should be doing on their own, and then deleting the post. All that time that people put into helping the asker is wasted, and they lose the reputation they gained.

If you're not comfortable [with the way we do things](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), you're probably better off not using Stack Overflow for your homework.

Another note: Do not vandalize your posts. If you have found an answer to your question, post it as an answer.